# Revocation of deny chnge permissions and deny change owner rule for AuthenticatedUsers on Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows

I created a deny rule for AuthenticatedUsers, thinking it meant authenticated over the domain, not all authenticated credentials. I expected it to be distinct from Everyone, but seems much the same group.

The rule denies change permissions and change owner, along with deletes. I was basically trying to prevent files being deleted by remote access.

The local and network admins all have full control, but the deny AuthenticatedUsers is taking precedence over all other rules.

I have switched off inheritance and tried to take ownership of a subfolder, so I can change permissions, but the rule appears propogated down the tree, and all attempts fail.

I have tried using ICACLS command line to take ownership and remove the rule both on the top level and sub-folders, but it fails or returns 0 changed results.

How do I revoke the deny rule?

Would it be possible to boot from a rescue disk/usb and remove the rule that way? If so, what would be the method/commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use elevated command prompt with the command:

```
ICACLS C:\Users /inheritance:e /remove:d "Authenticated Users"
```

The command returns a message saying 1 files changed, one file processed, which means it is successful.

ICACLS is the command to change security settings on files and folders.

C:\Users is where all the shared folder are, so easier to run at the top level.

/inheritance:e means enable inheritance for the command, ie run the command against all subfolder and files

/remove:d means remove all deny rules

"Authenticated Users" is the name of the principal which can be found in the user permissions for one of the shared folders - note many online solutions missed the space in the name or suggested finding the Sid and using that. I could not get it to work using Sid, returned 0 files changed every time.

After removing all the deny rules, all other access reverted to the expected behaviour and it was possible to create a specific group of users for deny rules, then add the users to the deny groups required individually.